# ksh associate arrays

Tags: associative-array, ksh

I have a script that needs to use associative arrays. Being new to `ksh`, I am unable to find anywhere that `ksh` supports associative arrays. When I try to use regular array syntax and assign, I get an error that index cannot be that big. Does `ksh` support associative arrays? If not, what is the alternative solution?

I need to do the following:

```
${array[$name]}=value
```

and later in the code, to read a value for

```
${array[$name]}
```

I have about 2000 values to be stored and read from the array every time this script runs.

Unfortunately, I cannot use `perl` due to the extent of legacy modules to be included inside the script. Appreciate any help, tips or techniques.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ksh `typeset` command is used to declare an associative array.

```
$ typeset -A age
$ age[bob]=42
$ age[alice]=31
$ print ${age[bob]}
42
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried that and I get the following error:

 $ ./test.sh 
 paramPassed: ./test.sh 0
./test.sh[6]: typeset: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.
I am running on AIX6.1

Comment: @Kiran: Try changing your shebang to `ksh93` instead of `ksh`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that works. However, just for my understanding, is ksh93 newer than the default ksh? Does ksh93 mean released in 93? Thanks

Comment: @Kiran - `ksh` usually refers to `ksh88`, the first year that it was available. `ksh93` refers to the newer (and slightly incompatible) version of korn shell. More info can be found here on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell or at the official korn shell website in the FAQ: http://www.kornshell.com/doc/faq.html