# What's the corresponding code for ksh88?

Tags: ksh

This works for ksh93, how can I make a similar code for ksh88?

```
$ typeset -A age
$ age["bob"]=42
$ age["alice"]=31
$ print ${age[bob]}
42
```

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do that, as `ksh88` only supports numeric array indexing, and a fairly limited implementation (indices must be between 0 and 1023, inclusive). As a gross hack, you could have two parallel arrays, such that `$key[123]="bob"` and `$value[123]=42` but then you'd have to search `key` linearly every time you needed to look something up. Another quaint possibility is to have variables like `age__bob` and access it with `eval \$age__$key` or something.

Comment: I see you must be coming from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394894/ksh-associate-array

Comment: @tripleee yes I'm coming from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't, ksh88 doesn't do associative arrays.

Longer answer: It depends on what you are trying to do. The following workaround should work, but might not be suitable for your scenario:

```
integer bob=0
integer alice=1
age[bob]=42
age[alice]=31
```

You can hack around shells that don't implement assoc. arrays (e.g with eval) but it is never pretty or fast.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, ksh88 does not support associative arrays.

Use ksh88 as wrapper around an awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  age["bob"]=42
  age["alice"]=31
  print age["bob"]
}'
42
```

A system that still hosts ksh88 and no ksh93 might have other languages that support mappings.